# VS code Unable to connect to Chrome debug port: 37095

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, flutter-web

I installed Flutter and VS Code in the following way:

```
$ sudo snap install --classic code
$ sudo snap install --classic flutter 
$ tail -n 1 ~/.bashrc
export CHROME_EXECUTABLE="/usr/bin/chromium"
```

```
$ flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.1, on Linux, locale en_AU.UTF-8)
    • Flutter version 2.2.1 at /home/debian/snap/flutter/common/flutter
    • Framework revision 02c026b03c (4 months ago), 2021-05-27 12:24:44 -0700
    • Engine revision 0fdb562ac8
    • Dart version 2.13.1

[✗] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
    ✗ Unable to locate Android SDK.
      Install Android Studio from: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      On first launch it will assist you in installing the Android SDK components.
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#android-setup for detailed instructions).
      If the Android SDK has been installed to a custom location, please use
      `flutter config --android-sdk` to update to that location.


[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • CHROME_EXECUTABLE = /usr/bin/chromium

[!] Android Studio (not installed)
    • Android Studio not found; download from https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#android-setup for detailed instructions).

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • Chrome (web) • chrome • web-javascript • Chromium 90.0.4430.212 built on Debian 11.0, running on Debian 11.0

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

I can start the Flutter app in terminal.

[image]

However, under VS code I get `Unable to connect to Chrome debug port: 37095`

[image]

What did I miss?

Answer (score 1):

If you work behind a proxy, you should set env `no_proxy=localhost,127.0.0.1`.
But if you are not using any proxy, try to install [Dart Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dart-debug-extension/eljbmlghnomdjgdjmbdekegdkbabckhm?hl=en-US).

Answer (score 0):

Try running `flutter clean` and then `flutter create .`

If that didn't worked out delete your `launch.json` in your `.vscode` directory and then run your app, this issue occurs if there are any misconfiguration in  **launch.json** file in vscode. and make sure your port is empty and not used by any other program such Microsoft IIS services or MySQL...

to make vscode `CTRL+F5` run in chrome or web-server go to your project root directory create `.vscode` directory and inside that folder add `launch.json` file.

Now if you want to run in web server only from vscode debugger then add this lines in you `launch.json`

```
{
 "version": "0.2.0",
 "configurations": [{
        "name": "Flutter",
        "request": "launch",
        "type": "dart",
        "args": ["-d", "web-server","--web-port", "8000"],
    }
]}
```

And if you want to launch in chrome device change argument `web-server` to `chome` i.e.

```
{   
 "version": "0.2.0",
 "configurations": [{
        "name": "Flutter",
        "request": "launch",
        "type": "dart",
        "args": ["-d", "chrome","--web-port", "8000"],
    }
]}
```

Now run `CTRL+F5`

If you don't have problem in changing your port then try running your program from terminal with `flutter run -d chrome --web-port XXXXX`

here XXXXX represents your port number.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is that chromium, flutter and VS code have to be installed through SNAP.

Answer (score 0):

in my case;

i was set the localhost to a local ip on hosts file of the OS  for remote development and forget it. that's why flutter run -d chrome gave the feedback connection refused.

solution:

in OSX, edit the hosts file located at /private/etc/hosts path and ensure localhost paired with 127.0.0.1

that's all.