# Flutter run app chorme closes with error Self-referential requests to this proxy server are forbidden

Tags: flutter

When I try to run flutter app, chrome browser opens and closes immediately with error "Self-referential requests to this proxy server are forbidden". The detailed message is;

Launching lib\main.dart on Chrome in debug mode...

Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...

Unexpected character

403 OK; body:

```
    "<HTML><TITLE>Forbidden</TITLE><H1>Self-referential requests to proxy are forbidden</H1>Self-referential requests to this proxy server are forbidden</HTML>"


#0      ChromeConnection.getTabs (package:webkit_inspection_protocol/webkit_inspection_protocol.dart:68:11)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      ChromiumLauncher._getFirstTab (package:flutter_tools/src/web/chrome.dart:432:11)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      ChromiumLauncher.connect (package:flutter_tools/src/web/chrome.dart:408:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      ChromiumDevice.startApp (package:flutter_tools/src/web/web_device.dart:145:17)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      ResidentWebRunner.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/isolated/resident_web_runner.dart:304:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      asyncGuard.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/async_guard.dart:111:24)
<asynchronous suspension>

Finished with error: Unable to connect to Chrome debug port: 64538
 Unexpected character
403 OK; body:
<HTML><TITLE>Forbidden</TITLE><H1>Self-referential requests to proxy are forbidden</H1>Self-referential requests to this proxy server are forbidden</HTML>
```

---

I have tried removing the system variables (Windows environment) http_proxy, https_proxy and no_proxy but no use. Tried opening the android studio as an administrator also but no use.

Comment: Did you try reproducing the error with an example code ?
If so please post it

Comment: I am trying to run the default main.dart which is created when we create a new flutter project

Comment: Can you post your pubspec.yaml file

Comment: It is the default pubspec.yaml file which is generated with any new flutter project

Comment: Maybe this could help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69216737/vs-code-unable-to-connect-to-chrome-debug-port-37095